# How to get specific column data by searching a specific name in same table from two Data Base?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-science

[image]

There are two schemas `D1` and `D2` which have the same table with different data called `Hotels`.

I need to get the data list of under `'Vista'` `name`, `ID`,`P-Email`, `D-Email`, `X-Email` and `Z-Email` from those two tables. Primary Key is `ID`. What is the query for this?

Comment: You can use [edit] button on the bottom-left of your actual question post.

Comment: Please provide the sample structure and data in text format so that you can get help much, faster, and easier.

Answer (score 0):

USE D1;
Select ID, P-Email, D-Email, X-Email, Z-Email from Hotels where Name ='Vista';

USE D2;
Select ID, P-Email, D-Email, X-Email, Z-Email from Hotels where Name ='Vista';

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `UNION`:

```
SELECT
  h.Name,
  h.ID,
  h.`P-Email`,
  h.`D-Email`,
  h.`X-Email`,
  h.`Z-Email`,
  'D1' AS Schema
FROM D1.Hotels h
WHERE h.Name = 'Vista'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  h.Name,
  h.ID,
  h.`P-Email`,
  h.`D-Email`,
  h.`X-Email`,
  h.`Z-Email`,
  'D2' AS Schema
FROM D2.Hotels h
WHERE h.Name = 'Vista'
;
```